# Adding route rule to Wordpress HTACCESS and keep the URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to add a rule to my .htaccess file that doesn't follow the Wordpress default rules.

Everything like this:

```
1- /course/(:any)
```

Must be redirected to this:

```
2- /course/?slug=$1
```

But I want to keep the URL in 1, without the query string.

Everything I try either gives me an internal server error or doesn't match the rule. This is what I got and is just being ignored (because the wordpress shows me a 'page not found' message). The resulting URL is like `http://localhost/bethmoda/courses/?slug` without the parameter and changing the URL

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/course/(.*)$ /bethmoda/course?slug=$2 [L]

RewriteBase /bethmoda/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /bethmoda/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How can I do this?

Comment: sorry, I didn't copy my htaccess content. it is edited now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
#Exclude /bethmoda/course/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bethmoda/course/index\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^/?bethmoda/course/(.+)$ /bethmoda/course/?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

The rewriteCond is important to avoid RewriteLoop error on the second rewrite iteration, otherwise without this condition You will get an Internal server error.

Comment: i'm getting an apache 404 error now. why is the `/index\.php$` part important?

Comment: index.php is the directory handler for your course dir. /course?slug=foo changes to /course/index.php?slug=foo on the second iteration and matches the pattern /course/(.*)$ causing an infinite loop error.

Comment: course is not a dir in my project. it's a wordpress page that responds to /bethmoda/course

Comment: In which case, I don't think this is meant to be done with `mod_rewrite`. Not a WordPress user, but I'm sure you can use the URI segments to your advantage, and remove the need for the `slug` parameter...

Answer (score 0):

The following is a wordpress way to achieve what you want.

If possbile: change "slug" with something else, lets say "course-slug".

```
//Add query variable, so that wordpress identifies your custom query string
function add_custom_query_var( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'course-slug';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var');
```

Add your custom rewrite rules

```
//Assumption: course is a page
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules )
{
  $pattern = "course/([^/]+)?$";
  $target  = "index.php?" . "name=course&course-slug=\$matches[1]";

  // If course was a custom post type
  // $target  = "index.php?" . "post_type=course&course-slug=\$matches[1]";

  // If course was a category
  // $target  = "index.php?" . "category_name=course&course-slug=\$matches[1]";

  // If course was a tag
  // $target  = "index.php?" . "tag=course&course-slug=\$matches[1]";

  $newRules[$pattern] = $target;

  return array_merge($newRules,$rewrite_rules);
}
```

Flush permalink

```
Step 1: In the main menu find "Settings > Permalinks". 
Step 2: Scroll down if needed and click "Save Changes". 
Step 3: Rewrite rules and permalinks are flushed.
```